# A function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ how to show that it is continuous at the point 0

Tags: real-analysis

The function is $$f( x )= \frac 1{1+x^2}$$ for every $x \in\mathbb{R}$. If I wanted to show that it is continuous at $x= 0$ would the proof be the same as showing it is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ using $\epsilon > 0$ ?

Comment: I don't see how. Could you write more details to show what you're thinking?

Comment: If you have proven that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, then surely $f$ is continuous, whence it is continuous at $0$.  However, I'm not sure what you are asking or what you have done.

Comment: I’m sorry for not clarifying. I wanted to show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is $\delta > 0$ st |x-a| < $\delta$ therefore |f(x) -f(a)| < $\epsilon$

Comment: The answer to your question as stated is not necessarily.  You can prove that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ without proving that $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $\Bbb R$.  However, if you do prove that $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $\Bbb R$, you will necessarily also prove that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$.  And it's probably not hard to generalize a proof that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ to a proof that $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments already mentioned, showing that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ implies continuity at every point. However, if you only need to prove continuity at $x = 0$, you could use a more direct method.

Since $f(0) = 1$, we need to find an appropriate bound for

$$\left| \frac{1}{1+x^2} - 1 \right| = \left|\frac{x^2}{1+x^2} \right| = \frac{x^2}{1+x^2}. $$

Using that $1 + x^2 \geq 1 \implies \frac{1}{1+x^2} \leq 1$ gives

$$\left| \frac{1}{1+x^2} - 1 \right| \leq x^2 = |x|^2 < \delta^2,$$
since we may assume that $0 < |x| < \delta.$ Then, you may simply choose $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon}$ to complete the argument.

Instead, if you want to prove $f$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, you need to bound

$$\left| \frac{1}{1+x^2} - \frac{1}{1+y^2} \right|$$

when $|x-y|$ is small. For this, I would try to use the Mean Value Theorem (assuming you have covered it already).